# Using the GData Objective-C api... Is there a way to get the statistics for a particular video from YouTube?

Tags: objective-c, gdata-api

All I can get is the snippet variable... nothing statistics related.
I'm trying to get the likes, dislikes, and duration of each particular video.

```
+(void) getListOfVideosFromSearchTerm: (NSString *) term usingCallback: (getListOfVideosCallback) callback{
    if (youTubeService.authorizer == nil) callback(nil);
  __block NSMutableArray *videosArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
    query.maxResults = 10;
    query.q = term;
    query.videoEmbeddable = @"true";
    query.type = @"video";

    GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [youTubeService executeQuery:query
                                   completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                       // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                       if (error == nil) {
                                           GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;

                                           // iteration of items and subscript access to items.
                                           for (GTLYouTubeSearchResult *item in products) {
                                               ILVVideo *newVideo = [[ILVVideo alloc] init];
                                               newVideo.title = item.snippet.title;
                                               newVideo.description = item.snippet.descriptionProperty;
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.urlForHighResolution = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.highResolutionSize = CGSizeMake([item.snippet.thumbnails.high.width floatValue], [item.snippet.thumbnails.high.height floatValue]);
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.urlForMediumResolution = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.mediumResolutionSize = CGSizeMake([item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.width floatValue], [item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.height floatValue]);
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.urlForStandardResolutionImage = item.snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;
                                               newVideo.thumbnail.standardResolutionSize = CGSizeMake([item.snippet.thumbnails.standard.width floatValue], [item.snippet.thumbnails.standard.height floatValue]);
                                               [videosArray addObject:newVideo];
                                               NSLog(@"%@",item.snippet.title);

                                           }
                                           callback(videosArray);
                                       }else{
                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                       }
                                   }];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Analytics is available via YouTube's new JSON-based API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

There are [generated classes](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Source/Services/YouTubeAnalytics/Generated) for the YouTube Analytics API in the [JSON-based Objective-C library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).